# Использование обученной модели нейронной сети

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

После обучения Tensorflow RNN модели в GoogleCoLab и сохранения чекпоинтов, появляются 4 файла:

- checkpoint
- 1.data-00000-of-00002
- 1.data-00001-of-00002
- 1.index
- checkpoint (указывает на последнюю модель)
- .data (содержит веса, таких файлов может быть много)
- .index (указывает какой файл .data какие веса содержит)

Вопросы такие:
Как использовать обученную Tensorflow RNN в GoogleCoLab на локальной машине?
Нужно скачать с CoLab файл с весами или какой-то другой, или их все?
И потом как использовать?
Разместить в корне, и можно ли импортить необходимые методы?
Или нужно сохранить модель в формат .h5 и после использовать?

Например создать простой prosto.py в котором:

- t = input()

И как в таком случае подать t в обученную модель?
Нужен ли для этого исходник модели?

Знающие, помогите пожалуйста!

Answer (score 2):

Существуют методы `save()` и `load()` для сохранения модели и последующей загрузки где хотите.
Для использования существует метод `predict()`

[Подробнее](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model)

Comment: При применении метода save() сохраняются чекпоинты в виде 4 файлов - модель, веса и указания что где.
Вопрос в том.. Как использовать эти файлы на локальной машине?

Comment: Архитектура модели - состоит из двух рекуррентных нейронных сетей: кодер RNN просто потребляет входные слова источника без каких-либо предсказаний; Декодер, с другой стороны, обрабатывает целевое предложение, предсказывая следующие слова.

Comment: @GaloGramma метод `load()` запускаешь из того же репозитория, где сохранил. Тоесть он загружает сразу весь репозиторий с твоей моделью. Далее с помощью метода `predict()` используешь модель для предсказания/генерации. Я так полагаю, у вас что-то вроде GAN. Тогда после обучения стоит сохранять именно генератор, т.к. дискриминатор нужен лишь на период обучения)

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ, но пока что не до конца понятен принцип.
Очень прошу Вас разъяснить более подробно!
Я пока не сохранял модель в репозиторий. На данном этапе я лишь обучил модель на ноутбуке Google CoLab используя простой дата сет и получил сохраненные файлы чекпоинтов. Скачал их с CoLab на лок маш и не понимаю, что с ними дальше делать.
Нужно ли восстанавливать исходную модель на лок маш?
Нужен ли .HDF5 для использования модели на лок маш?
Модель состоит из двух рекурентных сеток - (1)Encoder, (2)Decoder.

Comment: Для наглядности можете посмотреть [туториал от sentdex c этого момента](https://youtu.be/wQ8BIBpya2k?t=1041)